# How to check if matrix block type is empty or not

Tags: matrix, conditional

I have a matrix field with two different block types and I want create a conditional to check if one of the blocks is not empty show it and if it is show the other.  This is not working:

```
{% for block in entry.page.type('text, intro') %}
    {% if block.type.text != "" %}
        <h3>{{ block.text }}</h3>
    {% else %}
        {{ block.intro }}
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Thanks!

Comment: Wouldn't it be cleaner to show all the blocks in the field? How can you make sure there is a block with the other type just because there is no block with the first type? If your field contains matrix elements from both types, what should happen then?

Comment: This is for my search results so I just want to show one or the other. If it contained both it would just show text.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can fetch the number of entries for the first type, check if you receive an empty array if so fetch matrix blocks of type B

### Craft 2

```
{% set blocksTypeOne = entry.matrixFieldHandle.type('blockTypeHandle1').find() %}
{% if blocksTypeOne|length %}
     // blocks with type A exists
{% else %}
    {% set blocksWithTwo = entry.matrixFieldHandle.type('blockTypeHandle2').find()
    // do something with them
{% endif %}
```

### Update Craft 4 has finally dropped the `.find()` method

```
{% set blocksTypeOne = clone(entry.matrixFieldHandle).type('blockTypeHandle1').all() %}
{% if blocksTypeOne|length %}
    // blocks with type A exists
{% else %}
    {% set blocksWithTwo = clone(entry.matrixFieldHandle).type('blockTypeHandle2').all()
    // do something with them
{% endif %}
```

Comment: This technique no longer works as of Craft 4. Anyone have a solutions that works in Craft 4?

Comment: Craft 3 deprecated the `.find()` method, you need to use `.all()` now. The rest can be basically the same